# Flutter's issue with Google Indic Keyboard

Tags: flutter, dart

The Google Indic keyboard is not getting dismissed in real device when I click system back button but it is working fine with emulator.

```
          TextField(
              controller: _chat_text_form_controller,
              expands: false,
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.newline,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
              maxLines: null,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                contentPadding:
                EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 0),
                fillColor: Colors.white,
                filled: true,
                hintText: 'Type Text Here...',
                hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(25)),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red, width: 2),
                ),
              ),
            );
```

**Edit**

I have checked on other phones with different keyboards, unfortunately it has same behavior. I cannot dismiss soft keyboard from system back button but I can dismiss it programmatically.

Comment: are you upgrade flutter sdk?

Comment: @JunsuCho I did `flutter upgrade`

Comment: is this specific to indic keyboard? what physical device are you using?

Comment: @Doc Check my edit & I have checked with Vivo & Xiamoi

Comment: is this https://gitlab.com/indicproject/indic-keyboard the right one? or the one by google?

Comment: @Doc Google indic keyboard

Comment: Tested. Works as expected. Back button closes the keyboard.

Comment: could you paste the configuration?

Comment: @Doc It seems a flutter bug, it got solved after recent update.